# Finding the girth of a graph with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Does NetworkX have a method or function that I can use to figure the girth of a graph?

For context, I'm trying to verify that a Mycielskian graph that I'm constructing (I know that there NetworkX already has an algorithm for this) has a girth greater than 4.

Comment: Note that I know of, but there is `min(len(cycle) for cycle in nx.simple_cycles(G))`

Comment: @Stef does `simple_cycles(G)` returns all the possible cycles?

Comment: @micro5 Oh, you're right. I was confused and thought it only returned the induced cycles. But apparently what they call a "simple" cycle is just what I call a cycle. Documentation: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cycles.simple_cycles.html